# From time products to numberic products

Tags: python-3.x

I have a list of products which is defined by time (half-hour). I would like to change from time to numbers without have to use 48 if functions:

```
From:                   To:

0000                     1

0030                     2

0100                     3

0130                     4

....                    ...

2330                     48
```

Do you guys have any smart shortcut to this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to split the string into the hours and minutes parts. This can be done by slicing the string and then converting to integers.

From here, each hour represents `2` half-hours so we multiply by `2` and since you are saying the time `00:00` has one half-hour (?) we need to add `2` if there is `30` mins in the minutes parts, otherwise add just `1` to account for that initial offset. To check whether the minutes is `30`, we could do `==30` but since the only other case is `0`, we can just check the truthiness of the minutes value in a ternary.

So, the one liner:

```
def half_hour(t: str):
    return int(t[:2]) * 2 + (2 if int(t[2:]) else 1)
```

and some tests:

```
>>> half_hour('0000')
1
>>> half_hour('0030')
2
>>> half_hour('0100')
3
>>> half_hour('0130')
4
>>> half_hour('2330')
48
```

Comment: Great and creative answer!

Comment: "if int(t[2:])" does this tests if the minutes are more than 0?

Comment: @Deldar22 Yes exactly, `t[2:]` returns `'00'` or `'30'`. When converted to ints, these become `0` and `30`. `0` is equivalent to `False` and `30` is evaluated as `True`.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this with the `datetime` module if you wanted to. It's perhaps a little clumsy since time-only `datetime` instances are assumed to be on January 1, 1900, but it doesn't require that you do the string parsing yourself:

```
_epoch = datetime.datetime(1900, 1, 1)
_halfhour = datetime.timedelta(minutes=30)

def half_hour(time_string):
    parsed_time = datetime.datetime.strptime(time_string, '%H%M')
    delta = parsed_time - _epoch
    return delta // _halfhour + 1
```